# how to get related entities in dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: .net, silverlight, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We are currently developing a Silverlight webresource in the recently released Dynamics CRM 2011. At this moment we wanted to implement an autocomplete box displaying the collection of accounts, with their addresses. We are currently stuck at the relationship we needed to follow from the account entity to the address entity. 
At this moment I just graduated, any help will be highly appreciated.

We tried some things already like using the linked entities in the QueryExpression. At this moment we are improvising and implementing, the not most optimal way. We are getting the related entities from another request to the server.

thanks in advance.

Comment: @glennFerrieLive, I'm not using the OData service, I'm using the Soap service at this moment... thanks already for your time to respond

Comment: two things: 1) try odata, it will change your life. 2) have you tried executing 2 separate queries, the first to retrieve the Account Data and the second to retrieve the Address data?

Comment: I was trying that with 2 seperated queries by using the relationship class..

Comment: if you post sample code I'm confident I can get it to work for you.

Comment: I would suggest to use Fetchxml query, its easy to build the query using advanced find.

Comment: what is the question?  You could use a retrieveMultiple based on account id and populate a grid with it.  Is that not working?